# Socket PHP vive caindo

Tags: php, socket

Eu googlei e encontrei formas de trabalhar com o socket. Aí dei início ao serviço em minha VPS. 
No início estava funcionando tudo ok. Porém, agora, de instante em instante, o Socket cai, fazendo com que eu precise acessar o ssh a cada momento pra reiniciá-lo.

Saberiam me ajudar com essa questão, o que eu deveria fazer para resolver?

Comment: Tivemos um problema parecido aqui e era estouro de memória. Reiniciavamos a VM e ficava ok por uns dias até que começava de novo. Resolvemos alterando na VM o gerenciamento da memória. Não sei se é teu caso, mas é algo a investigar.

Comment: Interessante @Diego, faz sentido pois eu monitoro a VPS utilizando o htop e mostra muito pico, porém oscilação de servidor, no caso me confirme uma coisa por favor, o Socket se mantém aberto ou preciso fecha-lo e sempre abrir quando necessário?

Comment: Qual é o objetivo do uso do socket? Realizar algum processo em paralelo ou algo do tipo? Pergunto isso, pois, na maioria dos casos (conforme meu conhecimento), o socket deve ser aberto para realizar o processamento e, ao retornar os dados, fechado. Mas existem exceções.

Comment: @GabrielHeming estou usando socket para comunicação tanto de chat quanto notificações em tempo real da minha aplicação. Agora para o uso do chat já pensei em migrar para o Firebase da google, é uma boa ideia ou isso é relativo?

Comment: Eu tinha problemas parecido com o serviço do soket.io, então comecei usar o Forever e resolvi definitivamente: https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: Luiz, teria que dar mais detalhes, se tem algo no log de erros, detalhes de configuração e tudo o mais, até para ver se é um problema de programação ou de suporte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe um sistema de controle de processo que eu uso chamado [SupervisorD](http://supervisord.org/).

Ele te permite que você inicie um processo. O mesmo, caso o processo caia, trata de iniciá-lo novamente, de acordo com o que você configurar.

Você pode instalá-lo no Linux assim:

```
sudo apt install supervisor
```

Em seguida, você precisa iniciar o serviço

```
sudo service supervisor start
```

Após isso, você já pode começar a usar o `supervisor` para gerenciar seus processos.

Primeiro, você precisa criar um arquivo de configuração do mesmo na pasta `/etc/supervisor/conf.d` com a extensão `.conf`.

Por exemplo `nome-do-programa-ou-comando.conf`:

```
[program:nome-do-programa]

autorestart=true
autostart=true
command=php /meu/script/php_socket.php
numprocs=1
process_name=socket
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/projeto.log
user=wallace
```

Em seguida, você pode usar o comando `sudo supervisorclt update`. Provavelmente, o arquivo que você configurou será exibido.

Ao fazer isso, o seu processo será iniciado.

Se você precisar modificar o arquivo, poderá fazê-lo normalmente, sem parar o `supervisor`.

O que você precisará fazer é executar o comando `sudo supervisorctl reread` para ele reconhecer as alterações feitas e, em seguida, usar o comando `sudo supervisorclt update` para iniciar novamente o processo com as novas alterações.

Apesar de entender o básico sobre o SupervisorD, aqui na empresa foi muito útil para garantir que o processo responsável por executar filas nunca caísse. Foram raro os casos que tive problema ao usar o Supervisor.